How to create geometry from WKB?
I would like to create a polygon from wkb using pyqgis. I'll be getting data from governament service. Here's an example: https://uldk.gugik.gov.pl/?request=GetParcelById&id=141201_1.0001.1867/2 There is parcel geometry in wkb format (second line in this url).
I'm trying to create a polygon layer based on this data and an example of geometry handling showed in pyqgis docs: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html#geometry-construction In this example it's a point geometry and my code works fine for it (for this example I create point lyr), but I'm not getting any results with the polygon geometry from the first link. Why?
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=EPSG:2180', 'parcels', 'memory')
ft = QgsFeature()
g = QgsGeometry()
wkb = bytes.fromhex("010300002084080000010000000E000000931E86C64699244192E9D0891B741D41DBF97EF242992441C3F0110102741D41F4A963551A99244180F3E2341E741D41F4531C970F9924415EBBB401E0731D41AED4B380CF982441BF9A03840B741D41001E5119CB982441BB0A294FED731D4162139921CA982441F5BC1BDBED731D4123A12DF7C49824416286C653CE731D41554FE6EFB798244100378B87D7731D4174CFBA66AD98244173D53C5797731D4100E5EF2E859824416FBDA667B2731D41CEA62398A398244143E55F1B84741D41D6C8AEF4F1982441DCBA9BE751741D41931E86C64699244192E9D0891B741D41")
g.fromWkb(wkb)
ft.setGeometry(g)
layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([ft])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

Temporary layer is empty, but when I check this wkb in PostGIS I'm getting this result:
SELECT 
'010300002084080000010000000E000000931E86C64699244192E9D0891B741D41DBF97EF242992441C3F0110102741D41F4A963551A99244180F3E2341E741D41F4531C970F9924415EBBB401E0731D41AED4B380CF982441BF9A03840B741D41001E5119CB982441BB0A294FED731D4162139921CA982441F5BC1BDBED731D4123A12DF7C49824416286C653CE731D41554FE6EFB798244100378B87D7731D4174CFBA66AD98244173D53C5797731D4100E5EF2E859824416FBDA667B2731D41CEA62398A398244143E55F1B84741D41D6C8AEF4F1982441DCBA9BE751741D41931E86C64699244192E9D0891B741D41'::geometry
;



Is g valid? Does addfeatures return success?

Your data might actually be EWKB - a PostGIS format that embeds the SRID in the WKB format. This would explain why PostGIS is able to show the geometry. QGIS does not support creating a geometry from EWKB, see my related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/452532/187445

(Shapely can read the polygon using shapely.wkb.loads)

g is <QgsGeometry: null>, isGeosValid() returns False, but addFeatures returns True. I know that shapely can be used to read this geometry but I was looking for some "native" QGIS functions. CodeBard's comment with link to another question clarified everything. Thank you all for help.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html from WKB.
